# jdbcTemplate.queryForObject returning EmptyResultDataAccessException while normal query runs

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to change a normal query to Parameterized query using `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject` for avoiding SQL Injection. But the query returns `EmptyResultDataAccessException` - Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0 where the normal query works fine. Below is the normal query where i get the correct result.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String AcctNameBuilder = adhpDetailUtil.getAccName();
builder.append("select * " +    
                "from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY " +
                "where INSURANCE_ID = '" + request.getInsuranceId() + "' and " +
                "SYS_CD = '" + request.getSystemId() + "' and " +
                "ACCT_TYPE in (" + AcctNameBuilder.toString() + ")");
```

Here is  the parameterized query that i have created from the above query.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String AcctNameBuilder = adhpDetailUtil.getAccName();
    final String QUERY = "select * " +  "from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY " + "where INSURANCE_ID = ? and " + "SYS_CD = ? and " + "ACCT_TYPE in (?)";
    Object[] params = new Object[]  {
    request.getInsuranceId(),request.getSystemId(),AcctNameBuilder};
    String ids = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(QUERY, params, String.class);
    builder.append(ids)
```

In the first case, builder.append contains the exact query while in the second case `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject` is returning `EmptyResultDataAccessException`. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can just append ids for an "IN" clause like that.

The parameter for the "IN" clause is technically an Array. I ran into this a number of years ago and I don't think that this has ever been truly addressed.

If you think about it this is a fairly difficult problem as the query planner for preparing the statement cannot effectively bound the number of parameters.

Comment: am getting the same exception if i remove the IN clause from both the querys. Actually how can i prepare the query using the strings QUERY and params and save it in builder.

Comment: According to this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Class- This is supposed to return single row/single column ... you are trying to retrieve all columns.